# How does a superconductor moves along a line of magnets if it's flux-pinned?

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

So I saw a plenty of demonstrations where superconducting piece of material moves freely along a magnetic surface, usually a line of arranged magnets, and at the same time it is claimed that flux tubes are created inside a superconductor that "pin" it in place.

How can it freely move, even assuming magnetic fields are symmetrical along the magnetic track, aren't there still individual flux tubes going through it? I can only imagine a scenario where flux lines are not "tubes" but 2-dimensional fields that stretch through entire length of a rail, otherwise shouldn't individual flux lines still hold it in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a high-level answer: a superconductor resists changes in flux.  So you can move a superconducting bulk along a magnetic track because the flux it loses at one end is replaced by the flux it gains at the other, but you can't move it sideways because the flux it loses on one side is not replaced by flux it gains on the other.  At a microscopic level there are individual flux lines, but the total number of those through the material at any one time is basically constant.

Comment: could you advise some further reading or lectures on this? on magnetism and flux dynamics?

Comment: One nice introduction is Ginzburg, V. L., and E. A. Andryushin (2004), Superconductivity, Revised Edition, World Scientific. It mostly focuses on low temperature superconductors, which are not the ones you use for the magnetic track demonstration, but high temperature gets a mention and the book is both short and intuitive.  A more advanced treatment, with mathematics, is Ketterson, J.B, and S. N. Song (1999), Superconductivity, Cambridge University Press.

Comment: sounds good, thanks!